# cant work out how to use .focus in my assignment

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/Awolozzie/pen/VwVWXdJ

I need to fix this code to use .focus for the error messages in the innerhtml.

I have tried this as well as many different options but feel i have gone wrong from the beginning I am an external student and the lecturers have been of no help, more worried about the in-class students

```
    if (validateEmail(email)) {
        errorMsg.textContent = '';
        emailInput.classList.remove('error');
        // Do something with the valid email address
      } else {
        errorMsg.textContent = 'Invalid email address.';
        emailInput.classList.add('error');
        emailInput.focus();
      }
    });

    function validateEmail(email) {
      const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/;
      return regex.test(email);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you mean by *use .focus for the error messages in the innerhtml.*?

Answer (score 1):

you're missing part of the snippet

emailInput should be bound to an html element

```
const emailInput = document.getElemendById('email-input-id')

<input type="text" id="email-input-id" />
```

You need to show us where the email variable is beg set (it should be the value of the element

```
const email = emailInput.value 

validateEmail(email)
```

lastly you have not shown the handler that this logic should be inside

```
document.getElementById('submit-email').addEventListener(() => {
    const emailInput = document.getElemendById('email-input-id')
    const email = emailInput.value 

    if (validateEmail(email)) {
        errorMsg.textContent = '';
        emailInput.classList.remove('error');
        // Do something with the valid email address
      } else {
        errorMsg.textContent = 'Invalid email address.';
        emailInput.classList.add('error');
        emailInput.focus();
      }
    }
})

<input type="text" id="email-input-id" />
```

If you'd like more help I'd suggest looking at the guidelines for posting questions and amend your question with more detail.

Comment: the link goes to my complete code

Comment: https://codepen.io/Awolozzie/pen/VwVWXdJ

Comment: you need to follow the stackoverflow guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example eg: not post external links, the community is here to support you with a specifc problem not write your code for you, try chat gpt for that. It might also help to be clear about what outcome you are expecting. in this case focus simply puts the cursor on the input it is bound to.

Comment: note in your linked code, you're actually just submitting an html form and javascript is not intercepting anything, which would be immediately clear to someone trying to help you if you had followed the guideline.

Comment: That's fine I'm new here I have been in hospital and out during the course also the first tutor was on long service leave no one knew about, and the second tutor took leave for personal reasons which external students were not advised about and the most recent has only just responded to my questions with a " you have a week to submit .